# Can We Manipulate With User Touch Input

Tags: java, android

I want to Manipulate With User Touch Input for example if the user pressed on his screen at (10,30) coordinates can I make the phone read it as he pressed somewhere else

Comment: Not without overriding the touch HAL.

Comment: What do you need this for? You can override onTouch in your view.

Comment: I'm trying to let the user turn on gps without looking at screen but he can't do that unless he press ok in the popup screen .. so maybe I could let him press anywhere instead(except cancel ofcourse)

Comment: You can manipulate touch events _in your app_, if you want to redirect a touch event from your app to the system bar though, I think (and hope) that it wouldn't be possible without root privileges and heavy hackery.

Comment: I did it inside my app .. but too bad not outside it didn't work with broadcastreciever

Comment: I guess I should stop trying to do smart things XD